# Prepopulate sms with generated text in Android app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, sms

my task is to send sms message: generate one link and add some text e.g. This is your receipt: *[www.recipt.something](http://www.recipt.something)*

When user clicks on button send sms i need to populate sms field and that user can choose to which number they want to send that message.

[image]

This image is only example. I want to just use text from my app and paste it to sms app without number (here it's 123456789). Like when you want to write a new sms message.

I tried this:

```
val activity = context.findActivity()
    val intent = activity?.intent
    val smsPermission = checkSmsPermission(context)

    if (smsPermission) {
        Logger("SmsDialogContent").writeToLog("SMS PERMISSION TRUE")
        try {
        if(intent != null){
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:"))
            intent.putExtra("sms_body", "SOME TEXT")
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
```

Sms permissions are SEND and RECIEVE SMS.

EDIT: With this code when user clicks on button nothing happens.

Comment: If you are launching a text messaging app, you do not need any permissions. However, you have not explained what your problem is. You cite code that you tried -- what specific problems did you encounter?

Comment: Nothing happens and sms app doesnt open

Comment: Have you tried `ACTION_SEND` instead of `ACTION_VIEW`? See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common?hl=en#SendMessage). You might also use breakpoints or logging to confirm that your code is being executed. For example, I do not know why you have `if(intent != null)` there.